# failed to pass JSON object in anchor tag data template

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, eloquent

In laravel, my controller returns this [image: controller collection] collection, as you can see, it has another collection `evidences` as relations. How do I separate or use this collection. What I am already doing is in this code snippet below.

```
template: function (row) {
console.log("in return: ", row.evidences))
return '\
       <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" 
       title="Show details" \
       data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showModal" data-id="' + row.id +
       '" data-title="' + row.title +
       '" data-description="' + row.description +
       '" data-evidencedata="' + row.evidences+
       '">\
       <i class="la la-eye"></i>\
       </a>\
       ';
},
```

Now if I use `console.log(row.evidences)` in the above function before `return` statement it prints out the content that it holds and the type of `row.evidences` is `Object` because of which I can iterate through it and use it. Now the problems is when I try to access this `evidences collection` in another jquery function, I could not.

I am accessing it in this code snippet below

```
$('#showModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            let button = $(event.relatedTarget);
            let id = button.data('id');
            let modal = $(this);
            modal.find('form input#title').val(button.data('title'));
            modal.find('form textarea#description').val(button.data('description'));

            console.log("in show: ", button.data('evidencedata'))

        });
```

It also changed its type from `Object` to `String` which could not let me iterate through it. I have tried `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` but no result but I am able to access other data which I am sending along with it i.e. `title` and `description`.

What am I doing wrong here. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! the problem was with the *object-string*. It was being converted to string as data was being passed in data-template. So the simple solution to this problem was to convert the `Object` which is in my case is `row.evidences` to `String` using `JSON.Stringify(row.evidences)` and adjust the double and single quotes accordingly and then wherever I want to use that simply `button.data('evidencesdata')`, and use it using `forEach` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

`title` and `description` are working because they are already plain strings. You are defining a string of html text for your button. Any variable you use is turned into a string as well.

Since your `evidencesdata` is an object, this won't work correctly. You have 2 options:
1. Turn the object into json, than base-encode it (to avoid problems with quotes). Later you can base-decode it, and parse the json, and you'll have the object again.
2. Don't return a button string, but define a button object, and use the data functions to add the object to the button. (using jQuery `$("<button>").data(evidencesdata)`)

The second is probably better, in terms of JavaScript internals and objects in memory, but might impact your code more than the first option.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. My problem was resolved!